# Facebook app, change content based on page used under?

Tags: facebook

What I'd like to do is create one facebook app, which I've done, but then use it in multiple facebook pages passing a variable or setting based on the facebook page.

So, I have one app called 'home'. I want it as a tab in multiple pages, but I want to pass a variable or setting somehow, to the iframe, so I can create one app on my domain but have it display different content depending on which page it's being called from.

Make sense..?

We have multiple facebook pages, but the canvas settings only allow pointing to one url, but I don't want to have to create an app per facebook page.

I know when you view the apps installed on a facebook page you get a 'settings' option for each one, is there any way for me as a developer to create a new setting that appears there, that will be passed to the iframe somehow, so in my apps code I can display different content on different pages..?

Thanks in advance!

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is installed on a page, we automatically pass a `signed_request` that contains (amongst other things) the `page_id`, so you could customise your content based on that. There's more details on this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).